# Getting IE Automation Error "Object variable or with block variable not set"

Tags: excel, vba, automation, excel-automation, ie-automation

I am Getting error while automating an existing IE window.
error is

"Object Variable or with block variable not set"
Code is

```
Sub accessExistingIEBrowser()

      boolWindowFound = False
      Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
      WinCount = objShell.Windows.Count
      
       For winNo = 0 To (WinCount - 1)

          strURL = objShell.Windows(winNo).document.Location
          strTitle = objShell.Windows(winNo).document.Title
          If strTitle Like "Sample Form" Then
              Set IE = objShell.Windows(winNo)
              boolWindowFound = True
              Exit For
          Else
          End If

      Next

      If boolWindowFound Then
        Set doc = IE.document
        doc.getElementsByName("fname")(0).Value = "test"
      End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You are assuming that every window will have a non-null `document`. That is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

"Object Variable or with block variable not set" means that somewhere in your code you omit the **Set** statement.  Set a breakpoint at the beginning of this code (F9), start debugging (F5) and single-step (F8) through your code and you will find where.

Comment: Why the downvote? Breakpoints and single-stepping are primary to debugging code successfully.